# DELETE LOW_PRIORITY row visibility

Tags: mysql-5.5, locking, delete

I have a large MyISAM table on MySQL 5.5(Windows XP x64) on which I will have to run `DELETE LOW_PRIORITY` queries. Does `DELETE LOW_PRIORITY` make the rows invisible to `SELECT` statements immediately and actually delete the rows from disk when no clients are accessing the table, or is the point delaying removal of visibility?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rows remain visible. Test (1) shows that the `delete` does not prevent any rows from being visible to subsequent queries. Test (2) illustrates the table-lock taken immediately by a normal `delete` - the query waits until the `delete` finishes and returns a zero count.

**testbed and long running query:**

```sql
create database stack;
use stack;
--
create table my_table (id int auto_increment primary key, varchar_val varchar(10));
insert into my_table (varchar_val)
select 'HELLO'
from (select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) s1,
     (select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) s2,
     (select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) s3,
     (select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) s4;
--
select avg(t1.id), avg(t2.id), count(*) from my_table t1 cross join my_table t2;
--
```

**test (1): with low_priority:**

```sql
--session 2:
delete low_priority from stack.my_table;
/*
Query OK, 10000 rows affected (21.84 sec)
*/

--session 3:
select count(*) from stack.my_table;
/*
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|    10000 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
*/
```

**test (2): without `low_priority`**

```sql
--session 2:
delete low_priority from stack.my_table;
/*
Query OK, 10000 rows affected (21.15 sec)
*/

--session 3:
select count(*) from stack.my_table;
/*
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
1 row in set (18.10 sec)

*/
```

Answer (score 5):

From the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/delete.html):

> If you specify LOW_PRIORITY, the server delays execution of the DELETE until no other clients are reading from the table. This affects only storage engines that use only table-level locking.

All this means is that the `DELETE LOW_PRIORITY` statement will not begin processing until all read locks are finished. If another read lock comes in before the `DELETE LOW_PRIORITY` statement begins, it will wait.

Once the `DELETE LOW_PRIORITY` statement has the lock though, it will acquire the table-lock and run until complete (or killed).

Under normal [table lock](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/internal-locking.html) situations, any write requests will be given higher priority than read requests. Example: if you have a write lock going on, then a read request goes in the read queue, and then another write request comes in, the second write request will execute before the read requests.

Using `LOW_PRIORITY`, the situation is reversed. If a read lock is going on, and a write comes in, it will wait. If another read comes in before the write gets the lock, the second read will execute and the write will wait.

So, if you are using `DELETE LOW_PRIORITY` on a table that is frequently read from, the `DELETE LOW_PRIORITY` statement could be waiting a long time.

Once a write lock is acquired in a table-locking situation, any reads will wait in the queue until the write lock is finished.

Comment: It's not about 'visibility of rows'. You first need to understand how [table locks](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/internal-locking.html) work.